# Storing ints using HSET in redis

Tags: redis

I am using redis to store some numeric values using `HSET`. Here is an example command I am using

```
HSET "abc" "field" 123
```

I'm expecting this to store an integer, but when I do `HGETALL`, it turns out to be a string:

```
1) "field"
2) "123"
```

My two questions are:

1. Is there any way to store an integer in redis using `HSET`?
2. Is there any space saving benefit of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://redis.io/topics/protocol#integer-reply:

> The following commands will reply with an integer reply: SETNX, DEL,
>   EXISTS, INCR, INCRBY, DECR, DECRBY, DBSIZE, LASTSAVE, RENAMENX, MOVE,
>   LLEN, SADD, SREM, SISMEMBER, SCARD.

The reply for `HSET` is a string, but it doesn't mean that Redis stored your info as such.

From http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization

> Since Redis 2.2 many data types are optimized to use less space up to
>   a certain size. **Hashes, Lists, Sets composed of just integers**, and
>   Sorted Sets, when smaller than a given number of elements, and up to a
>   maximum element size, are encoded in a very memory efficient way that
>   uses up to 10 times less memory (with 5 time less memory used being
>   the average saving).

Also in this page there are commands to configure Redis to set threshold for that optimization.